# Google chart vAxes was broke in 2 lines, and was shifted while browser height was changed

Tags: google-visualization

The original issue can be found [here](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2331)

ENV: **WIN7, chrome 51.0.2704.103 m**

I put my code on jsFiddle , but jsFiddle can't show it in full screen, so I also put code on Plunker
[go to jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shandeai520/zx82c14a/4/)
[go to Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/scoquDJqtr5gJPRhtfEH?p=preview)

Reproduce step:
1. go to Plunker and click preview to show the result page in full screen
2. drag window's bottom line up and down, you will see legend was shifting. and separated

---

Any comments on the following points will be appreciated:

1. Why are there 2 lines?
2. Is it possible to force the usage of a single line?
3. If 2. isn't possible then can the shifting be avoided since the `(Number)` should be on the right?

[image]

**After browser height was changed, two lines shifted**

[image]

Comment: A general practice on SO to post the issue here instead of just providing a link to it. This is done to ensure that, if at some point the URL becomes invalid, the question doesn't become unsalvageable due to lack of info.

Comment: @rbaleksandar,sorry for the bad behavior.

Comment: Np. Also screenshots of code instead of actually writing the code here is another bad practice. If people want to help you they have to retype everything from the screenshot which is definitely time wasted considering that a simple copy-paste of a code block is the better option here.

Comment: updated jsFiddle and Plunker, and reproduce steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by increased height from 250px to 255px.
The whole discussion on [github](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2331)

```
<div google-chart chart="chartMid" style="height:250px; width:50%;"> </div>

<div google-chart chart="chartMid" style="height:255px; width:50%;"> </div>
```